# Is it possible to download and view images onto the user's device on VodaPay Mini-programs?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

One of my requirements to to download files onto the user's device from my VodaPay mini-program so that the user can view/open it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in that way. Part of the sandboxing of mini-programs entails that you can have your internal file structure in your mini-programs where you can view and store your files, but it’s not possible to store these files on the user’s device storage.